# A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column - when saving object

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Every time I try to save something into the database I get the error:

```
A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'PackageId'.
```

Following is the code that does this, the line `DB.SaveChanges();`.

```
public ActionResult CreatePackage(Package package, string MaterialId, string SubCategoryId, string Companies)
        {
            ModelState.Clear();

            //add stuff to package
            package.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;

            DB.Packages.Add(package);
            DB.SaveChanges();

            return Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Material") + "#Packages");
        }
```

Below is the diagram of the table that throws the exception:

[image]

After doing some heavy reasearch I on stackoverflow I believe that there might be something wrong with my foreign keys:

- [A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384659/a-dependent-property-in-a-referentialconstraint-is-mapped-to-a-store-generated-c)
- [A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'ID'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642566/a-dependent-property-in-a-referentialconstraint-is-mapped-to-a-store-generated-c)
- [A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'FeeID'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982957/a-dependent-property-in-a-referentialconstraint-is-mapped-to-a-store-generated-c)

However I can't see to find what can possibl be wrong with my code, nor my DB. I am trying to create a many-to-many relationship between the table Packages and COmpany. A Company can be in several packages, and a packes can be used by several companies.

What I find odd, is that this only happens when I try to create a new object. For example, If I have a Package with `PackageId = 0` and a Company with `CompanyId = 0` and if I run the SQL server statement:

```
INSERT INTO GATE_Package_Company
VALUES (0, 0);
```

Everything works fine because the previous object already exist. But if I try to create a new Pacakge object (one that does not exist yet) and I try to save it, I get the error. Right now it is simply not possible to add new packages :S

What am I missing?

Comment: If you run a trace on the Insert, what does the resulting SQL command(s) look like? It might be a timing issue insofar that the package does not exist (or committed) at the point you try to inject the other record.

Comment: how do I run a trace on the insert?

Comment: You can use SQL profiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on Visual Studio. By deleting the table from the ´.edmx´ file and re-importing it from the database again, the problem was fixed.

I am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013, and I have no idea if this problem is particular to this version or if it also affects other versions.

All I know is that I wasted 2 days with this. I honestly hope this answer can help someone else in the future.